# Change symfony2 login_check URL

Tags: php, symfony

I'm implementing a Symfony 2 solution according to a set specification. The specification states that the login form at GET /login must resumbit to POST /login.

How can I change the URL for the /login_check? Can I create a route that calls the security controller directly, like the following? I don't see any controller in the Security bundle.

```yaml
oft_auth_login:
    pattern: /login
    defaults: { _controller: MagicSecurityBundle:Default:login_check }
    methods: [POST]
```

According to the documentation for *security.yml*,

> check_path (type: string, default: /login_check) This is the route or
> path that your login form must submit to. The firewall will intercept
> any requests (POST requests only, by default) to this URL and process
> the submitted login credentials.

So I have to create a valid route, but I can't figure out where it's supposed to point to (firewall action? security action?) or what it's supposed to do.

I changed it to POST /login, but it said it couldn't find it...

Now I have a *security.yml* file that looks like this:

```yaml
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: oft_auth_login
            check_path: oft_auth_login_check
            username_parameter: user
            password_parameter: passwd
```

And a *routing.yml* that looks like this:

```yaml
oft_auth_login:
    pattern: /login
    defaults: { _controller: OftAuthBundle:Default:login }
    methods: [GET]

oft_auth_login_check:
    pattern: /login
    methods: [POST]
```

I can load the form fine (GET /login), and the form method is POST and the action is /login, but when I submit it, I get the following error (404, route not found):

> Unable to find the controller for path "/login". Maybe you forgot
> to add the matching route in your routing configuration?  404 Not
> Found - NotFoundHttpException

What code, firewall methods, etc. would I have to call to authenticate a user in a custom *check_login* method, or any other way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, which is to access and post the login form to the same URL (/login)?

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be configured in `security.yml`?

Comment: *Change login_check url* Do you mean to change the pattern so that instead of /login_check it be something different?

Comment: yes, exactly, I want it to be POST /login (same path as the GET URL to load the form)

Comment: I think you need to define a routing called e.g. `login1` with the GET and put that out of your firewall (anonymous access) then the main routing for `login` with POST and `login_check`; Of course you can change the url of `login_check` to anything you want but you need to define them in your security.yml e.g `login_path: /path/to/login/with/post` and `check_path: /custom/path/to/login_check`

Comment: It's an old question but I am building a Silex app and I have some trouble (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236815/silex-2-security-firewall-error-with-locale-silex-securityserviceprovider-p). Everything work fine but when I am not in my default `locale`, I have trouble with `/{_locale}/login_check` and  `/{_locale}/logout`. How can I redirect from `/{_locale}/login_check` to `/login_check` with the `$_POST` data ? I created a new route `$app->post('/{_locale}/login_check'...` where I get `$_POST` (`_username` + `_password`) but it doesn't connect my user as he does when I have no locale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *security.yml*, you should see something like:

```yaml
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false

    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /secured
```

In your *routing.yml*, you should see something like:

```yaml
## Security Routes
default:
    pattern:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: SecurityBundle:Security:login }

login:
    pattern:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: SecurityBundle:Security:login }

login_check:
    pattern:   /login_check

logout:
    pattern: /logout
```

Change `check_path: /login_check` in security.yml to `check_path: /new_login_check`

Change `pattern:   /login_check` in routing.yml to `pattern:   /new_login_check`

That will change the URL for the login check route.

Your login form probably looks like:

```
<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
```

The `{{ path('login_check') }}` twig snippet outputs the URL to the route identified by `login_check`. This is not the same as a URL. Example routing configuration (using YAML):

```yaml
route_identifier:
    pattern: /relative/url/path
    defaults: {_controller: ExampleBundle:Example:test}
```

Using the path('route_identifier') function will route to the URL /relative/URL/path, which calls the method *testAction* in the ExampleController class in the ExampleBundle.

You should always use Symfony's routing where possible in your templates, so you avoid conflicts and can easily change routes.

Somewhat orthogonal to changing the login check route, but rereading your question, it says that you want to use the /login path for different actions depending on GET/POST. This requires an extra step, as Symfony will choose the first matching route available to use.

After following the above, your *routing.yml* might contain something like:

```yaml
## Security Routes
default:
    pattern:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: SecurityBundle:Security:login }

login:
    pattern:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: SecurityBundle:Security:login }

login_check:
    pattern:   /login

logout:
    pattern: /logout
```

As such, it'll only ever match the login route, never the *login_check* route. You'll need to specify a method as well:

```yaml
## Security Routes
default:
    pattern:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: SecurityBundle:Security:login }

login:
    pattern:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: SecurityBundle:Security:login }
    methods:   [GET]

login_check:
    pattern:   /login
    methods:   [POST]

logout:
    pattern: /logout
```

See the Symfony documentation on [Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) for more information.

Another issue you will run into is that the *login_check* route must match the firewall the user is logging into, but the login route must be accessible to non-authenticated users!

From Symfony's documentation:

> Next, make sure that your check_path URL (e.g. /login_check) is behind the firewall you're using for your form login (in this example, the single firewall matches all URLs, including /login_check). If /login_check doesn't match any firewall, you'll receive a Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check" exception.

This is a bit tricky when using the same URL for both actions, but it is possible. The biggest hurdle is that you can't match firewalls by an http method. The first thing you need to do, then, is make sure that both login routes only match your main firewall, by removing any firewalls that specifically match the login routes.

In the example above, that means removing this section from the *security.yml*:

```yaml
    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false
```

That'll meet the first requirement of *login_check* matching the firewall you're using, but unauthenticated users won't be able to reach the login route any more! That causes a redirect loop. Fortunately, there's a way around that. In your *security.yml* file, below the section firewalls, you should see a section called *access_control*. (If not, make one.) You'll need to add the following line to the **top** of this section. (Again, Symfony matching is conservative, quitting once it finds the first match.)

```yaml
access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, methods: [GET] }
```

That will explicitly allow anonymous users to access the /login path, but only via GET.

Comment: Hi Kal, using the security routes as described above (with GET and POST), I get an "Unable to find the controller for path "/auth/login". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration? " error when I submit the form. Is there a route/controller that I can point at? Any other ideas? thx

Comment: Hey, @Nostradamnit. Sorry about that, I only tested the first part (changing the login_check route), not using the same url for both login and login_check. There's a bit of a hurdle involving matching the routes to specific firewalls, see my updated answer. I've tested this successfully using Symfony 2.3.3, so if you still have any issues, let me know which version you're using. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my configuration to only use the */login* route with Symfony 3.1:

File *security.yml*:

```yaml
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false
        methods: [GET]

    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            login_path: login #this use the route name and not the pattern
            check_path: login_check # same here : route name
        logout:
            path: logout

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, methods: [GET] }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER}
```

File *routing.yml*:

```yaml
login_check:
    path: /login
    methods: [POST]
logout:
    path: /logout
```

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
```

And this is working for me:

- /login with GET gives me the controller.
- /login with POST to submit the form.